# Как можно воспроизвести два файла по очереди?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно воспроизвести два файла mp3 или ogg по очереди? Пробовал через `new Audio()` но звук воспроизводится одновременно. Нужно чтобы это происходило при запуске функции в консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если всего 2, то например:

```js
function MethodTwo(){
    var a=document.getElementById("audio-1");
    var b=document.getElementById("audio-2");
    a.play();
    a.addEventListener('ended',function(){
      b.play();
    }, false);   
}

MethodTwo();
```

```html
<audio id="audio-1" controls>
  <source src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg' type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<audio id="audio-2" controls>
  <source src='https://zvukov.com/files/sound_264.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```